# Continuous running head title through section break and different numbering? Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I am writing an APA style document where I want to have the same running head title throughout. I have formatted the document with 2 sets of numbering, before and after the contents page. Is it possible for the running head to continue through the section break without starting from "Running head: title" again?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, sorted it out. Different first page was selected in the second section. Turned it off and linked to previous and it seemed to work.